# How to rename different UV maps in blender 2.74

Tags: cycles-render-engine

In every tutorial i've seen, there is a Name field under the "UV Maps" section of the Data for an object.  The latest tutorial i've seen said simply it was version 2.7.  I am using Cycles renderer.

However I have no Name field, nothing in right click, and nothing I could see in the UVs menu seems to have anything to do with naming it.

How can I rename my multiple UV maps?

Edit:  I didn't think to ask about renaming vertex groups because it wasn't obvious to me that they would have anything in common.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can now <kbd>Double-Click</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Click</kbd>) on the name of items in 'UI Lists' and they will change into an editable text field. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the new name once typed.